# atom editor appearance white and black

Tags: atom-editor

My atom editor used to look all black, but now it looks like this, black and some white black. Can someone tell me how to fix it? Thank you. [image]

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A change](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/12696) that [fixes this issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12634#issuecomment-302436306) has been merged into master. It should go out into the next beta release.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the editor theme in `Atom -> Preferences -> Themes` which you can also reach with `Shift-Cmd-P` and then typing `Show Preferences`

Comment: But which theme should I choose? I have the default one dark now

Answer (score 1):

Verify your atom version it's now  1.17.0, I just had a problem with atom and all I had to do is update it . Don't worry your settings won't be lost

Comment: in that case I thnk you have to set a new theme, there's a lot a great themes for atom just check this https://atom.io/themes/

Answer (score 1):

Change the display color to default, which is color lcd, then it will be resolved.