# Why does my Atom program look like this?

Tags: atom-editor

I keep getting this gray space around the right side of my code in Atom. Not sure how to fix this. If anyone has experienced this and found a solution, please let me know!

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked up the color scheme in Atom to see what that color coorelates to?

Comment: Do you have panes open?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [atom editor appearance white and black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081766/atom-editor-appearance-white-and-black)